# Can't start PowerShell as administrator

Tags: powershell, administrator

I have Windows 7, and I want to run PowerShell as an administrator. I found it in the Start Menu, right clicked it and selected *Run as administrator*, but I get the following:

> Windows Explorer has stopped working

Even if I I try to open PowerShell > Windows PowerShell Help, I have the same error. I only can start PowerShell as a regular user, but this is useless because I can't run the following command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
(ExecutionPolicy : Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft .PowerShell' is denied.)
```

Any ideas why I can't start PowerShell with admin rights?

Comment: Just to confirm: You are an administrator on the local computer?

Comment: Check the event log for details on the crash and post the info.

Comment: Try downloading and installing the latest version of PowerShell. (That's version 5.1.) If it is already installed, try removing and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 3):

you can run cmd.exe as admin and start powershell.exe

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained exactly how to do that.

Comment: This answer is simple enough.  I don't generally expect to need to explain how to press the Alt-Ctrl-Delete combination, or explain what a "double click" is.  Dumbing down SuperUser too much could quintruple average answer length.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'm not sure what the issue is. What I would suggest trying though is going directly to the PowerShell exe and trying to run that as an administrator:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe
```

Failing that, I would run regedit as an administrator and change the registry key manually:

```
C:\Windows\System32\regedit.exe
```

Answer (score -1):

You can run any command as Admin (assuming you have the rights), by just typing it (for example "powershell") without the quotes, and once found, hold CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER to launch it as admin. The error you're describing sounds like a basic configuration issue though. If that doesn't work, I would definitely reinstall powershell. you can verify it's location exists and the executable is there by going to:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

> or for the 32 bit version:

```
%SystemRoot%\Syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Comment: I did forget to mention ENTER, but I'm on my first cup of coffee.

CONTROL + SHIFT + ENTER and the suggestion is still valid. If you have the necessary rights, it will launch the program with administrator rights. I should note this is NOT from the run menu though, rather with just the 'found' results when typing after hitting the windows key or start button (if applicable).

Answer (score -2):

i have the same issue, the solution i found is you go to control panel-> user account-> change user account control setting -> drag down the bar to the lowest, i don't know how it work, but it wor