# Why might PowerShell in Windows 7 return " 'Export-WindowsDriver' is not recognised"?

Tags: windows-7, powershell, export

Trying to export Windows 7 drivers using PowerShell as recommended by [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEzPTOEpNUg).

I set PowerShell, with the rest of the requisite command, from the search box, after having checked [this other SuperUser thread](https://superuser.com/questions/312326/cant-start-powershell-as-administrator).

And it returns:

> 'Export-WindowsDriver' is not recognised

Even though this command is defined in PowerShell as shown in [this Microsoft support document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/export-windowsdriver?view=windowsserver2019-ps&viewFallbackFrom=winserver2012-ps).

Advice please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some PowerShell commands depend on the operating system version due to APIs not being available in older versions. The `Export-WindowsDriver` cmdlet was added in Windows 8.1 / Server 2012 R2 so you'll have to use way to export the drivers.

You can try using DISM (the PowerShell cmdlet uses the same interface under the hood):

### Source

```
mkdir C:\drivers-backup
dism /online /export-driver /destination:C:\drivers-backup
```

If the dism command does not work for some reason you can also manually backup the following folder and restore from there:

```
C:\Windows\System32\DRIVERSTORE
```

### Destination

And on the new machine either via command line:

```
# Option a)
pnputil.exe /add-driver C:\drivers-backup\*.inf /subdirs /install

# Option b)
dism /online /Add-Driver /Driver:C:\drivers-backup /Recurse
```

... or manually:

1. Open Device Manager. Due to lack of driver installation, some devices have a little yellow question mark over its icon, and they should have more descriptive names.
2. Select a device from the device tree, right-click on it and select “Update Driver Software” from the drop-down
3. In the pop-up window, you will see two options. Click Browse my computer for driver software.
4. Click on Browse to find the location of the driver files you backed up previously and click Next. Make sure the “Include subfolders” option is checked.
5. After a while you’ll see the message saying “Windows has successfully updated your driver software” and now the device name should be displayed correctly.

Comment: AH! - Just read your 2nd source - I've got nearly 2GB of files in three subfolders of DRIVERSTORE. Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: @iSeeker - `/export-driver` is a Windows 8.1 Update+ only DISM function.  "Exports all third-party driver packages from a Windows image to a destination path. The exported drivers can then be injected to an offline image by running the DISM Add-Driver command. This command is new for Windows 8.1 Update." [Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-driver-servicing-command-line-options-s14)

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for the clarification. I was misled by a you-tube claiming 'Export-windowsdriver' was valid for Win7, and comments appeared to validate the suggestion. Then on an MS site I saw the date 2012 under 'export-windows'. and assumed (wrongly) that it indicated validity prior to Win8.1.

Comment: BTW: Why would someone downvote an honest question that had already involved some careful checking? Are non-experts discouraged from trying to learn?

Comment: Supplementary question to @megamorf : Will you Destination solutions work on reinstalled Win7 ?

Comment: @iSeeker: Some users are going around downvoting Windows 7 questions solely on the basis that it's Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks @carveone I'm aware the cognoscenti regard it as not the latest, but frankly, it suits me (as apparently it still does about 60% of existing windows users), particularly for WMC in my case, and my security softwares (plural) have kept me safe so far.

Comment: @iSeeker - 60% of Windows users being on Windows 7 is an extremely overinflated number. [It's more like 20%](https://www.netmarketshare.com/operating-system-market-share.aspx). The only thing that prevents me from upvoting this answer, is the suggestion to use a command, that is incompatible with Windows 7 (or at least there is not disclaimer it won't work).

Comment: @Ramhound: Ah, see that's a perfectly valid reason not to upvote an answer. What I was saying is that I'm seeing validly posed and constructed questions (ie: *not* a "do my homework for me" question!) being downvoted solely because they mention particular software or OS or hardware. Which, as far as I'm concerned, is an abuse of the SO voting system. And this comment is probably off topic :-)

Comment: Voting on contributions you find unhelpful because they are about an unsupported operating system is certainly NOT abuse of the voting system.  There certainly are users who will literally upvote any contribution, I have even seen spam upvoted, tough to explain the logic on that one.  My point is that one of the "suggested" reasons to downvote, is if a contribution isn't helpful.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for correcting my outdated info re % of Win7 users. But am I to understand that I shouldn't be posting questions relating to an unsupported OS on SU? If not, where would you suggest, please?

Comment: @iSeeker - I am not saying that in the slightest.  I just disagree that downvoting a question due to it being about Windows 7 isn’t a violation of the rules.  It’s a single downvote which was countered by an upvote worth 5x the reputation.

Comment: @Ramhound. Understood and thanks to the counter-voter. Appreciated - even if this comment stream ought by now to be in Chat...

Comment: @Ramhound Obviously I couldn't tell who it was, so I deliberately wrote "to the counter-voter", meaning whoever...  ; - >